# Magento : get Group Price of Product

Tags: magento-1.8, php, api, price-rules, price

how can i get group price of a product via api ? i can get special price via api [Product info API](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogProduct/catalog_product.info.html)

is it possible to get group price ? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are you using tier pricing to set different prices for customer groups?  If so, try this:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogProductTierPrice/catalogProductTierPrice.html

Comment: no i want to get Group Price , Admin panel >>> Catalog >>> Manage Products >>> product page >>> Prices >>> Group Price